# Proving a set is countably infinite $\left \{q \in \Bbb Q:q=\dfrac{a}{b}\ \text{where $a$ is even and $b$ is odd} \right \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Proving a set is countably infinite 
$$\left \{q \in \Bbb Q:q=\dfrac{a}{b}\  \text{where $a$ is even and $b$ is odd} \right \}$$

I am not sure how to go about solving this problem. I know it has something to do with Cantor Diagonalization, but I am not sure how to exclude the items that do not meet the criteria of the set.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite? Do you see why the set you described is infinite?

Comment: It has nothing to do with diagonalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the set is countable because is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. Now is infinite because the set $A=\{\frac{2n}{2n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite. This follows from the fact that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$ ($\mathbb{N}$ is infinite). And from the fact that $A$ is a subset of your set.